# Spring MVC validations Not working

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I am a newbie in spring validations.I have a **loginform.html** with 4 text fields and i was trying to validate them but the *validations are not working* in my form.
But it accepts each and every value i entered.

*For example : If i enter an improper email it should throw me an validation error like "Enter proper Email ID*"

***loginform.java***

```java
public class loginform {
    @NotEmpty
    private String user;

    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String email;        

    @NotEmpty(message = "Phone should not be blank.")
    @Size(min = 10,max = 10)
    private String phone;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Enter your blog URL")
    @URL
    private String blog;
    // Get and set methods}
```

***login.html***

```html
<form:form action="login.html" commandName="userDetails">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><font face="verdana" size="2px">User</font></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
    <font face="verdana" size="2">
    <form:input path="user" /> <form:errors path="user"></form:errors>
    </font>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><font face="verdana" size="2px">Email</font></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
    <font face="verdana" size="2">
    <form:input path="email" /> <form:errors path="email"></form:errors>
    </font>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><font face="verdana" size="2px">Phone</font></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
    <font face="verdana" size="2">
    <form:input path="phone" /> <form:errors path="phone"></form:errors>
    </font>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><font face="verdana" size="2px">Blog</font></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
    <font face="verdana" size="2">
    <form:input path="blog" /> <form:errors path="blog"></form:errors>
    </font>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form:form>
```

***ContactController.java***

```java
@Controller
public class ContactController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String get(ModelMap model) {
    loginform ud = new loginform();
     ud.setUser("prem");
     ud.setEmail("@gmail.com");
    model.addAttribute("userDetails",ud);
    return "login"; 
}

@RequestMapping("/login")
public String loginCheck(@Valid loginform userDetails, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "login";
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("lfobj", userDetails);
        return "success";
    }
}
```

***spring-servlet.xml***

```xml
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller" /> 

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="basename" value="props" />
</bean>
```

***success.html***

```html
<body>
<font face="verdana" size="2">Welcome Mr. <b>${lfobj.user}</b>,<br>
Validations Success..!<br><br>
<u>You Entered</u><br>
</font>

<table>
    <tr><td>Email</td><td>${lfobj.email}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Phone</td><td>${lfobj.phone}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Website</td><td>${lfobj.blog}</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

***props.properties***

```
NotEmpty.userDetails.user = User Name is required
NotEmpty.userDetails.email = Email is required

Email.userDetails.email = Enter valid email Id
URL.userDetails.email = Enter valid URL
```

**OUTPUT** : While running :(loginform.html - getting inputs)

```
*User :  sriprem 
Email :  sri 
Phone :  1323sri 
Blog :   nice*
```

**It has show me the eror from my "props.properties" file but it doesnt show just directly gets all my input !!**

```
Success.html

Welcome Mr. sriprem,
Validations Success..!

You Entered
Email   prem 
Phone   1234sri 
Website nice
```

In above scenario everything was in wrong format yet it accepts the data ! Can anyone tell me what was wrong in my validations.

Comment: Can you make your problem a little clearer? It's not easy to figure out what is wrong

Comment: actually my data is not validated .If i gave a wrong email format it should give me "enter the valid email id" message from my "props" file.But it actually accepts everything.

Comment: Just now i have updated my Question.Can you identity what was my mistake ? - @geoand

Answer (score 0):

Follow the spring documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch05s07.html

Have you configure Bean Validation Implementation? Take a look to the point *5.7.3 Configuring a DataBinder*